# C Segmentation fault after adding a printf function. Works fine after commenting out

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, printf

I get segmentation fault after executing this part of code.If i comment the first printf out,it works fine.Why does this happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Func (int *a){
    printf("%d\n",56 );
  printf("a is %d\n",*a );
  return 3;
}


int main(){
  int N, i, Planet, *a,junk;

    junk=scanf("%d", &N );
    *a = N;
    Planet = Func(a);
    printf("%d\n", Planet);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: you're not allocating any space for `int *a`. Dereferencing an unintialized pointer (your `*a = N;` line) is undefined behavior

Comment: Have you tried compiling with all warnings enabled: one of those warnings will tell you the cause of your segfault.

Comment: To clarify a little further, you have an `int *` called `a` that basically points *nowhere*. When you do `*a = N;`, you're telling the computer to go to that *nowhere* location, and write down the contents of `N` at that spot. This is what is causing the segfault.

Comment: - so instead of dereferencing a and going to nowhere, you should assign a the address of N, or a = &N; Then you can dereference a later to get the value of N.

Comment: @turbulencetoo Strictly speaking, `a` doesn't point _nowhere_, it points _somewhere_. The problem is that you have no idea where _somewhere_ is. It might even be a valid pointer, causing you to accidentally overwrite some other important value in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `main` function, you defined the `int *a` pointer variable:

> ```
> int main(){
>   int N, i, Planet, *a,junk;
> ```

But then you dereferenced the pointer without having previously allocated any memory for it, nor setting it to point to something meaningful:

> ```
>  *a = N;
> ```

This results in undefined behavior.

What you probably wanted is to make `a` point to `N`?
If so, this is the correct syntax:

```
a = &N;
```

Now you can use `*a` to write some content into `N`.

---

**P.S.**
As a general rule, I'd suggest you to declare one variable per line, and initialize pointers to `NULL`, e.g.:

```
int man() {
  int *a = NULL;
  ...
```

Comment: I got it,but why did it run properly after commenting out the first printf?

Comment: @user7375077: You may want to inspect the generated assembly for that to figure out what the compiled code actually did and what are the differences between the two cases. `*a = N` for uninitialized `a` is _undefined behavior_: everything can happen.